# how to implement phonegap plugins in external JS file?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a Phonegap app, that would open an external URL with **super.loadUrl("http://example.com/index.html")**

On that page I have included some Javascript code for a Phonegap Plugin. Is it possible to call a plugin from external Javascript file? I don't see why shouldn't work, but it doesn't.

My plugin is FileTransfer plugin. When I run the app with a local index.html all works fine, but I need to run an external script which calls the FileTransfer plugin. Is that possible? Does anybody tried it before ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked in the Phonegap IRC and they say NO. Of course this could be a big security threat. 
I also asked if it would be possible to include internal JS scripts in my external HTML file. And the answer is also NO. The best way is to turn the web app into an native app, and have all the scripts locally.